# C++ Why does an assignment in a primitive double array seem to be much faster than a double variable assignment?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, variable-assignment

I am trying to program a simplified version of the Mandelbrot-set algorithm. But calculating Z_n+1 by storing every single Z for one pixel in an array and using Z[n] to calculate Z[n+1] seems to be faster than just storing Z_n to claculate Z_n+1. Which does not make much sense to me.

I am programming this in C++ with Qt, running in release mode.

Version one (fast):

```
    // inside QWidget-class
    int numberIterations = 500;
    double dw = width();
    double dh = height();
    int iw = width();
    int ih = height();
    int colors[iw][ih] = {};
    double cr = 0.0;
    double cc = 0.0;
    double zr[numberIterations] = {0.0};
    double zc[numberIterations] = {0.0};
    for (int x = 0; x < iw; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++) {
            cr = ((double)x/dw)*3.0-2.0;
            cc = ((double)y/dh)*2.0-1.0;

            colors[x][y]=0;

            QTime time;
            time.start();
            for(int n=1; n<numberIterations; n++){

                zr[n] = zr[n-1]*zr[n-1] -(zc[n-1]*zc[n-1]) + cr;
                zc[n] = zr[n-1]*zc[n-1] + cc;

                if(qAbs(zr[n])>2.0 || qAbs(zc[n])>2.0){ // to simplify it
                    colors[x][y]=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            qDebug() << time.elapsed(); // prints almost always 0 (ms)
        }
    }
```

As you can see, i seperate the real part of the complex number Z and the i part. By solving the binomial, it is really easy to claculate it that way, but it actually is not important in this case, since the actual calculation is the same.
Version 2 (slow):

```
// ... 
    double zr = 0.0;
    double zc = 0.0;
    double zr_old = 0.0;
    for (int x = 0; x < iw; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++) {
            cr = ((double)x/dw)*3.0-2.0;
            cc = ((double)y/dh)*2.0-1.0;

            colors[x][y]=0;

            QTime time;
            time.start();
            for(int n=1; n<numberIterations; n++){

                zr_old = zr;
                zr = zr*zr -(zc*zc) + cr;
                zc = zr_old*zc + cc;

                if(qAbs(zr)>2.0 || qAbs(zc)>2.0){
                    colors[x][y]=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            qDebug() << time.elapsed(); // prints about 2 on average (0-6)
        }
    }
```

It's sounds really strange to me that accessing an element in a double array at an index is faster than just using a double variable... is this actually the case or am I missing something that makes the inner for loop (with n) much slower when using the variables (and one extra assignment of course)?
Probably I am just blind right now but I just don't get it sorry...

## EDIT 1

My second version is wrong as Dmytro Dadyka pointed out. In the arrays the first element is always zero (convention) but I didn't zero the variables insinde the pixel loops when switching to the next pixel which gave me wrong times for a senseful computation since the number of iteration of the inner for loop is greater then. It needs to be:

```
    // ...
    double zr = 0.0;
    double zc = 0.0;
    for (int x = 0; x < iw; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++) {
            zr = 0.0;
            zc = 0.0;
            for(int n=1; n<numberIterations; n++){
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

But the time it takes to compute all values for the pixels is still about 10% longer with this version than with the array version. Which is strange since it should take more instructions as pointed Garf365 out.

Comment: How do you observe that one is faster than the other ? Can you us process to bench both code and also results you observe ?

Comment: I just used a QTime counter and printed it. Statistically the first version is much faster, that the second one. But I just add it to the question if it helps

Comment: Are you testing optimized release build?

Comment: Move the timing to the outermost level so the timer is only started and stopped once.

Comment: All these `(double)` casts here are unnecessary. If one of the arguments to a binary expression is a `double` the other one is implicitly converted to double.

Comment: There isn't much value in timing unoptimized code.

Comment: I am not testing optimized release build. Normal Debug mode, I edited the question. @interjay oh, really? Well I couldn't tell how the optimization at export would optimize these lines, but of course it could be an option.

Comment: @mep, Never test the debug version performance. It makes no sense.

Comment: @mep debug mode - easy to debug, performance comes a distant second;  release  (optimised for speed) mode - fast code hard to debug.  Don't waste your (our time) measuring the performance of debug builds.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that sorry. I will just try optimized release

Comment: So, just running in release mode should optimize it out? Well, running in release definately is faster, but the difference isn't gone. The second version is still much slower.

Comment: Comparing both compiled code with optimization (-O1), using gcc 9.1, just computation of zr/zc takes less instructions using variables instead of arrays (10 vs 12 instructions see https://godbolt.org/z/2oK6s-). Compute and test of absolute value is also wining by variable instead of array (12 vs 15 instructions) -- For small/medium arrays, time difference will so insignificant that, IMHO, optimization should not be the priority, but readability. And, also IMHO, don't optimize before it is really needed (ie, you observe in your final app that is a problem)

Comment: @mep Add obtained the time to the question

Comment: I think I understand what's wrong. Your examples are not computationally equivalent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you give are not equivalent. Initial `zr` and `zc` value in first case is `zr[0] = 0`, `zc[0] = 0` and is the same for each `(x, y)` pixel. In second case initial `zr` and `zc` values is final values of previous pixel. I think it breaks the computing logic  and you get wrong iteration count in second case. Fix your code by `zr` and `zc` initializing in the loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < iw; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < ih; y++) {
        cr = ((double)x/dw)*3.0-2.0;
        cc = ((double)y/dh)*2.0-1.0;
        double zr = 0.0;
        double zc = 0.0;
```

Comment: Oh yes, you are very right, thank you, this is the kind of answer I was hoping for. I declared the variables outside the loops but always set it so zero inside now and it's still a tiny bit slower (about 10%). But the helpful url in the comment by @Graf365 shows a benefit in performance using the variable version...

Comment: @mep I'm not sure that differences of about 10% can be estimated in such a simple way that you use. Most likely the results are identical. For more confidence, you can compare the output assembler.

Comment: At lest the 10% are very constant (no matter if in a range of some 10ms or some 1000ms, I tried with different resolutions).

Comment: Well, I assume, that these 10% come from the additional assignments, so I will mark yours as the answer because it shows the actual problem.